# Getting text from a specified tkinter label on mouse click

Tags: python, tkinter

```
books = []
result = db.answer_query(query)
for item in result:
    book = Label(search_page,text=item,font="none 12 bold",pady=2)  
    book.grid(row=row_count, column=0, sticky = W)
    books.append(book)
    row_count += 1
for book in books:
    book.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: BookInfoPage(book.cget("text")))
    book.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=book: h.configure(fg="#638cbb"))
    book.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=book: h.configure(fg="#000000"))
```

This is the current code which loads multiple labels and places them on successive rows of each index in a list returned from `db.answer_query(query)`. This function returns a list of string values.

The current issue that I have is that for the `"<Button-1>"` event, I pass the parameter `book.cget("text")` into the function `BookInfoPage()` which is a function that provides information about the clicked book name (provided from the labels). I want to pass text from a specified tkinter label on mouse click into the function `BookInfoPage()` but currently it passes the text from the **last** label only, no matter which label is clicked.

This is because *book* variable is recognised as the last entity in the list from the for loop. Is there any way around this issue?

I want to be able to pass text from a specified tkinter label on mouse click into the function `BookInfoPage()`.

Here is a video (gif) of the current working application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXjZ7.jpg

See that even though I click on "harry potter" it gives me the result for "the great gasby", the **last** entry in the list.

Comment: By the time that `lambda` gets called, the `for` loop has long since finished, and `book` is left with its value from the final iteration.  You *know* how to fix this, you did so for the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` bindings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event` object passed to the callback can tell you which widget you clicked on. Instead of throwing away the `event` object, use it:

```
book.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: BookInfoPage(event.widget.cget("text")))
```

An arguably better solution is to call a proper function, and use the `event` object to get the widget that was clicked on. Using a function is easier to write, easier to read, and easier to debug.

```
def show_book(event):
    book = event.widget
    BookInfoPage(book.cget("text"))

book.bind("<Button-1>", show_book)
```